# IA32 - Software Initialization Code Address Larger than Physical Memory Range

Tags: operating-system, boot, x86

From *Intel Software Developer's Manual*.

**Following a hardware reset (either through a power-up or the assertion of

 the RESET# pin) the processor is placed in real-address mode and begins

 executing software initialization code from physical address FFFFFFF0H.**

Now question is:

What if momory size less than FFFFFFF0H bytes, such as 2GB?

Comment: You probably want some nonvolatile memory (like ROM) mapped at that place, having RAM over there won't help you much.

Comment: @fvu Here the **software initialization code** means BIOS code who resides in CMOS?

Comment: BIOS code resides in some form of ROM (EPROM or nowadays flash), the CMOS RAM just contains some nonvolatile info that the BIOS needs to know about the machine.  It's been a long time since I messed around with computers at that low level, but I don't even think CMOS RAM gets mapped in the address space.  You may want to consult the schematics for the old IBM AT.  Although old, due to the fact that the logic on these boards is a whole lot less dense they're easier to understand, and the basic principles behind these boards is not that much different from what current boards do.

Comment: But indeed, the software initialization code is part of the BIOS.

Comment: @fvu Is the first instruction of **software initialization code** in BIOS and address FFFFFFF0H is mapped in ROM who contains BIOS?

Comment: Well the processor just jumps there and will executed whatever instruction it will find there, as that address really at the end of the address space quite often the instruction at that location will just be a jmp to the actual begin of the code, eg in PCs it will jump to the entrypoint of the BIOS code.  There are **plenty** sources of BIOS replacements available (google for openbios or freebios to get started) and study these codes.